# Magento 2.3.3 - Cash On Delivery payment method not showing in checkout page

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.3.3

I am using `cash on delivery` & `check/make order` payment method but it is not displayed in frontend.

I am using `slowin theme` to create eCommerce website.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Please check cash on delivery is enable or not from backend.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh yes enabled but after chcekout 'no payment method is available' msg displayed

Comment: Clear cache `php bin/magento cache:clean` and check it.

Comment: Did you flushed Magento cache ?

Comment: @DhadukMitesh yes of course

Comment: can you just check if its displaying in frontend but due to some css getting display none class or text being white or so? or are you getting any console errors?

Comment: @AmolBhandariSJ  A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at <URL> was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at <URL> and <URL> this error is accur

Comment: Just make sure you enabled cash on delivery for the required store view. Check the store scope